# Is there a reward for beating the Blue Sphere bonus stages?

Tags: sonic-mania

At each checkpoint in Sonic Mania, you can play a Blue Sphere bonus minigame as a callback to Sonic 3.

Having never played Sonic 3, I'm absolutely terrible at these and haven't been able to complete a single one.

[image: Blue sphere Minigame]

Is there a reward for completing these Blue Sphere minigames?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completing a Blue Sphere bonus stage earns you silver and gold medals which unlock Extras and Secrets. There are 32 medals to collect in total to unlock every Extra and Secret.

Medals are carried over between playthroughs, meaning you can play though the game multiple times on different save files to get them all.

## Unlocks

#### Secrets Menu

- **1 medal**: Super Peel Out (from Sonic CD)

  - Alternative to the Spin Dash which charges from a standing position.
- **7* medals**: Insta-Shield (from Sonic 3 & Knuckles)

  - Creates a shield to avoid damage for a split-second.
- **12* medals**: & Knuckles Mode

  - Replaces Sonic & Tails with [Knuckles & Knuckles](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/knuckles)
- **16 medals**: Debug Mode

  - Allows object to be placed anywhere in a level

#### Extras Menu

- **20 medals**: Dr. Robotnik's Mean Bean Machine (Puyo Puyo)

  - Featured as the Chemical Plant Zone Act 2 boss
  - Five different speeds to try
  - Play against AI or Human in local multiplayer
- **24 medals**: [D.A. Garden](https://youtu.be/UakVZi4N_Wc?t=313)

  - Interactive visualizer and sound test mode.
- **32 medals**: Blue Spheres

  - Unlocks Blue Spheres mini game on the Extras Menu
  - Selectable options for Original or Mania style

<sub>*Actual number of medals required may be less.</sub>

## Accessing the Secrets Menu

To open the Secrets Menu, highlight the ‘No Save’ section in the file select in Mania Mode. The will now have a new button labeled 'Secrets'. (△ on PS4; X on Switch; Y on Xbox). Note that the Secrets Menu can only be used in 'No Save' mode.

[image: Completed Secrets menu]
<sub>[Screenshot courtesy of VG247](https://www.vg247.com/2017/08/16/sonic-mania-cheats-unlockables-and-extras-to-return-to-the-cheat-friendly-spirit-of-the-90s/)</sub>

## Accessing the Extras Menu

The Extras Menu can be found at the bottom of the Main Menu below "Competition" and "Options". You can track your collected medals here.

[image: Completed Extras menu with 32 medals]
<sub>[Screenshot courtesy of VG247](https://www.vg247.com/2017/08/16/sonic-mania-cheats-unlockables-and-extras-to-return-to-the-cheat-friendly-spirit-of-the-90s/)</sub>

#### Sources

- VG247: [Sonic Mania cheats, unlockables and extras to return to the cheat-friendly spirit of the 90s](https://www.vg247.com/2017/08/16/sonic-mania-cheats-unlockables-and-extras-to-return-to-the-cheat-friendly-spirit-of-the-90s/)
- Gameranx: [Sonic Mania: All Blue Sphere Bonus Stage Rewards | Unlock Guide](http://gameranx.com/features/id/115650/article/sonic-mania-all-blue-sphere-bonus-stage-rewards-unlock-guide/)
- Eurogamer: [Sonic Mania unlockables and cheats: Debug mode, Super Peel Out, Extra unlocks, Level Select and other secrets explained](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-08-18-sonic-mania-unlockables-cheats-debug-super-peel-out-extra-modes-4843)
- Destructoid: [Did you know Sonic Mania has unlockable goodies?](https://www.destructoid.com/did-you-know-sonic-mania-has-unlockable-goodies--455048.phtml)
- YouTube: [WHAT HAPPENS WHEN YOU GET THE FINAL MEDAL IN SONIC MANIA?](https://youtu.be/K-9SI-bbqAo)
- YouTube: [Sonic Mania - D.A. Garden unlocked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgiO3RM4epI)
- Nintendo Life: [How To Unlock Mean Bean Mode In Sonic Mania](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/08/guide_how_to_unlock_mean_bean_mode_in_sonic_mania)
- Arqade: [What is the D.A. Garden?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/317431/181240)

Answer (score 3):

From [this site](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-08-18-sonic-mania-special-stages-chaos-emeralds-gold-medals-ufo-blue-sphere-4843), beating these stages earns medals that unlock extra modes in the game's Extras menu:

> If you have 25 rings and hit a mid-level signpost, a ring will appear above that you can leap through, taking you to a special stage. Completing these will earn you a silver or gold medal, depending on your performance, which then unlock bonus modes from the Extras menu. Progress carries over between playthroughs, so no need to get them all in a single sitting.