# Why can't I see the "Extra" content?

Tags: sonic-mania

I think that I have a problem within my game.

I have the PC version which I download directly from Steam.
[I've already beaten the game once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzgJc.png), and collected 3 emeralds, [and 17 medals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XnYN.png).

I can't see "Dr. Robotnik's Mean Bean Machine" in the Extras menu. I also can't see any button to activate any of the prior Sonic abilities which I should have by now.

I don't know if it's a bug or that I have hadn't done something yet that I should have

Comment: @StevenVascellaro The tags you added seem unnecessary. This is not a technical issue, and is not a problem specific with the PC version of the game.

Comment: Removed extra tags - as @DanmakuGrazer pointed out, they're not actually necessary for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try checking the "Secrets" menu by hovering over "No Save" in Mania Mode.**

Based on the number of medals you've unlocked (17), I don't think you've unlocked any content in the Extras menu yet. [Nintendo Life claims you need at least 20 medals to unlock Mean Bean Machine](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/08/guide_how_to_unlock_mean_bean_mode_in_sonic_mania).

To clarify, Sonic Mania has two different menus for unlockable content: ***Extras*** and ***Secrets***

#### Secrets Menu

- (1 medal) Super Peel Out
- (7-ish medals) Insta-shield
- (12-ish medals) & Knuckles Mode
- (16 medals) Debug Mode

#### Extras Menu

- (20 medals) Mean Bean Machine ([Source](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/08/guide_how_to_unlock_mean_bean_mode_in_sonic_mania))
- (24 medals) D.A. Garden
- (32 medals) Blue Spheres

For more information, see [*Is there a reward for beating the Blue Sphere bonus stages?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/316583/181240)

Comment: How can I access the secret menu? (specifically in the PC version)

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Go to mania mode and hover over the "No Save" option. There should be a prompt below saying what button you need to press. (if you take a screenshot, I'll add it to my answer)