# Is there any way to skip the Chemical Plant Zone Act 2 Boss?

Tags: sonic-mania

I absolutely hated the game Dr. Robotnik's Mean Bean Machine for the Genesis/Mega Drive.

Imagine my surprise when I'm playing Sonic Mania and I'm suddenly dropped into this game as a boss fight in Chemical Plant Zone Act 2.

Is there any way to legitimately skip this boss?

Comment: If you don't mind playing no save mode, you can use a cheat code to access the built-in debug mode then fly over to the goal post.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I don't think "activating a cheat code" really qualifies as "legitimately skip[ping] this boss". A "cheat" is pretty much the complete antonym of "legitimacy".

Comment: @StevenVascellaro yes, which would require you to have beaten this boss at least once already.

Comment: @Vemonus You can also unlock Debug Mode by collecting 16 medals from Blue Sphere. I added it as a comment since I'm not sure if that's what OP was looking for

Comment: @Vemonus You can access Blue Sphere stages from every goalpost in the game, so it's very possible to have beaten 16 of them by them... although unlikely.  Still, you could keep farming them until you do.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  Even with Debug Mode enabled, it is usually difficult or impossible to completely skip bosses, this one included (aside from just placing a goal post).  Luckily, the AI for this encounter is not very good, so it shouldn't take more than a couple tries to beat it.

If you need more practice playing Mean Bean Machine, you can [unlock the ability to play the game by getting 20 silver medals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317348/96435) in the blue sphere minigames.  You'll be able to play against various AI difficulties until you're good enough to beat Chemical Plant Act 2 easily.

Comment: What happens if you try to fly over the boss with Debug Mode?