# What is the D.A. Garden?

Tags: sonic-mania

In [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/316583/96435) on Sonic Mania, it says that you'll unlock something called the "D.A. Garden" if you get a certain number of medals from the blue sphere mini-game.  What is that and is there a reason behind the name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The D.A. Garden is a feature included in a few Sonic games as an extra. It's essentially an interactive sound test (like a visualizer). This name was first used for the Sound Test in Sonic CD, though I haven't seen any explanation for why it was named that.

From [this article explaining the extras](http://abadpassword.com/2017/08/20/guide-unlock-sonic-manias-extras-secret-modes/):

> And the D.A. Garden – Also known as the Sound Test. This was what Sonic CD’s Sound Test was called.

Also, from [the IGN Cheats and Secrets guide for Sonic Mania](http://m.ign.com/wikis/sonic-mania/Cheats_and_Secrets):

> D.A. GARDEN
>
> Here, Sonic Mania's soundtrack is available to listen to on demand.

Comment: Unrelated, but the embedded music video is really giving me some Original Starcraft Terran campaign vibes...

Comment: I found a video directly showing off the DA Garden in Sonic Mania. Feel free to embed it in your answer. https://youtu.be/UakVZi4N_Wc?t=313

Answer (score 2):

It's called D.A. Garden because in Sonic CD, it was used to listen to the high-quality .cda audio on the disk, referred to as D.A. (Disk Audio). I'm not sure about Garden though.

Also, there is a separate sound test option in Sonic CD that is easier to unlock than D.A Garden, and is used to access a few hidden images and a secret 8th special stage by entering codes. In that sound test, you can listen to all sound effects and music (except intro and ending FMVs).