# How many Blue Sphere stages are in Sonic Mania?

Tags: sonic-mania

While working on my [Blue Sphere unlock guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/316583/181240), I've started noticing that the bonus stages sometimes repeat themselves.

This means that, unlike the standalone Blue Sphere (which had [134,217,728 levels](http://info.sonicretro.org/Blue_Sphere#Gameplay)), Sonic Mania most likely has a limited pool of pre-made bonus stages.

**How many unique Blue Sphere bonus stages are in Sonic Mania?**

Comment: The link you provided says that the standalone Blue Sphere repeated levels as well.

Comment: @KevinWorkman "after level 128,016,000, some stages are recycled" I mean, after playing 100,000,000+ stages, then yes, *technically* the original would repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sonic Mania has 32 premade Blue Sphere bonus stages accessible from checkpoints.<sup>[1](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-09-01-sonic-mania-special-stages-chaos-emeralds-gold-medals-ufo-blue-sphere-4843),[2](http://www.ign.com/wikis/sonic-mania/Blue_Sphere_Stages),[3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPAksNP_TsY&t=1325)</sup>**

> Blue Sphere is based on the special stages seen in Sonic 3, with 32 unique stages, each one rewarding you silver or gold medals based on your performance.
>   <sub>[Eurogamer - Sonic Mania special stages](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-09-01-sonic-mania-special-stages-chaos-emeralds-gold-medals-ufo-blue-sphere-4843)</sub>

**Additionally, collecting 32 medals will unlock a near infinite supply of randomly generated Blue Sphere stages in the Extras Menu.**

> Collecting every single Blue Sphere metal will unlock Blue
>   Sphere mode where you can play a million or so versions of
>   procedurally generated Blue Sphere stages.
>
> These new sphere stages
>   have two types of modes:
>
> - Sonic 3 & Knuckles: Which is what we all know
>     and love
> - Mania Mode: Which introduces brand new mechanics into the
>     blue sphere game, such as spheres that need to be collected twice or
>     spirits that will teleport you across the map
>
> <sup>[Sonic Mania: The Completionist Review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPAksNP_TsY&t=1649) ([27:29](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPAksNP_TsY&t=1649))</sup>

For reference, GameXplain has a 50 minute video showcasing all 32 premade bonus stages.

**Sources**

- [**That One Video Gamer**: Sonic Mania - The Completionist Review featuring Tails Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPAksNP_TsY) ([22:05](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPAksNP_TsY&t=1325) & [27:29](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPAksNP_TsY&t=1649))
- [**Eurogamer**: Sonic Mania special stages](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-09-01-sonic-mania-special-stages-chaos-emeralds-gold-medals-ufo-blue-sphere-4843)
- [**GameXplain**: Sonic Mania - All Bonus Stages (Blue Sphere)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKIWS67al-0)
- [**IGN Wiki**: Blue Sphere Stages](http://www.ign.com/wikis/sonic-mania/Blue_Sphere_Stages)